# How can All Might still fight using One For All in the latest movie?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In the rematch fight with All For One, All Might had used his last embers of One For All and told Midoriya that he couldn't fight anymore, but in the latest movie we saw that All Might was using One For All and I wanna know how? How can All Might still fight and maintain his muscle form for that long?

Answer (score 3):

You are right, All Might has weakened significantly after his fight with All for One. It would be contradictory to show that he can still fight a powerful villain after that. However, *the movie happened before his fight with All for One*. As quoted from Horikoshi [here](https://comicbook.com/anime/2018/08/01/my-hero-academia-movie-timeline-confirmed-anime/),

> "Yes, the events of the movie happen before the battle with All For One, so I want everyone to be able to watch and look forward to this since you will never see their duo move in the manga."

The movie is set after the Final Exams, so roughly between **Episode 38 and 39**, while the fight between All Might and All For One happened in **Episodes 47 to 49**.